# add_user_meta() vs update_user_meta()

Tags: user-meta

I'm looking at the docs for `add_user_meta()` vs `update_user_meta()`.

If the current meta_key does not exist for a user, will `update_user_meta()` automatically add the meta_key for that user or do you have to define the meta_key with `add_user_meta()` first?

Comment: What isn't clear in the docs? ["If the meta field for the user does not exist, it will be added."](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta)

Comment: Overlooked that.  I was having issues with the metas not being added and didn't know if `add_user_meta()` needed to be defined first.

Comment: So, solved then?

Comment: This portion of it, yes--Thank you.  Still have to debug... :/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have already found out that using `update_user_meta()` if the meta field for the user does not exist, it will be added. ie `update_user_meta()` can do the task of `add_user_meta()`

However, the difference between them is the `return values`

### update_user_meta()

returns **False** if no change was made (if the new value was the same as previous value) or if the update failed, umeta_id if the value was different and the update a success.

**NOTE: as of v3.4.2 it returns the umeta_id on success (instead of true) and false on** failure

### add_user_meta()

return **Primary key id for success**. No value (blank) for failure. Primary key id for success.

Comment: I wanna add that the add_user_meta cannot update existing user_meta if the unique flag passed in is set to true.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your explanation, i will just add to yours the `update_user_meta()` also return true if successful update happened.

In short - It returns Meta ID if the key didn't exist, true on successful update, false on failure.